# How to create something like `matching` environment from examdesign in eqexam

Tags: exam

I use [eqexam](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/eqexam) package to create an exam with single-choice, multiple-choice and fill-in questions.  I chose it for visual appeal, easy localization / translation and ability to randomize answers.

What it is lacking is support for **matching tests** (i.e. connecting a set of answers on the left with set of answers on the right), something like 'matching' environment from [examdesign](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/examdesign) class.

How to create support for matching tests for `eqexam`, or how to port 'matching' environment from `examdesign` into `eqexam`?

Comment: Could you provide a M(N)WE? In the generality of the question as is, I would suggest using both packages.